# Login System - Reading from a file and comparing values to allow or deny entry to the system

Tags: python, file, authentication, system

I am designing a login system. I have done hashing for passwords, and I want python to read from a file and compare the value the user has enterred to the one in a file, if they match, then the user can enter the system.

Here is my code:

```
username = input("Enter your username: ")
password = input("Enter your password: ")

#hashing
p = len(password)+3
hashValue = 0
for element in password:
    hashValue += ord(element)*(37**(p*3+2))
    p += 1

#file reading
searchfile = open("users.txt","r")
for line in searchfile:
    if username in line:
        print(line)
        passwordFile = searchfile.readline()
        print(passwordFile)
        if password == passwordFile:
            print("Succesfully logged in.")
        else:
            print("Denied.")
```

And here is the content of the file:

```
user1
5682064547402171341935718587051072007223952507159509922486300727280224437681256157289392848984758601859653014989196589
user2
5459242799619652684746638604361187538149455998072046842553294309854609933784480688770064676790163754304952120716010653
```

First hash value = password123
Second hash value = password321

I think the problem here is that when python reads the next line, it reads it with an empty space (\n) and that is why when it compares it to the value enterred, it doesn't work. I do not know how to avoid reading it. Please help.

I have also tried putting the values from the file into a dictionary, however that did not work either.

```
upD = {}

with open ("users.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key,val) = line.split()
        upD[key] = val
        print(upD)
        if password in upD[username]:
            print("Welcome.")
        else:
            print("Denied.")
```

When I tried this, I stored the content of the file like this:

```
user1   5682064547402171341935718587051072007223952507159509922486300727280224437681256157289392848984758601859653014989196589
user2   5459242799619652684746638604361187538149455998072046842553294309854609933784480688770064676790163754304952120716010653
```

If there is another way of doing it please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can't mix file iteration (`for line in searchfile`) with other forms of file access (`searchfile.readline()`). Try `passwordFile = next(searchfile)` instead.

2) You are comparing the cleartext `password` variable with the hash from the `users.txt` file. Try `if hashValue == int(passwordFile)` instead.

```
username = input("Enter your username: ")
password = input("Enter your password: ")

#hashing
p = len(password)+3
hashValue = 0
for element in password:
    hashValue += ord(element)*(37**(p*3+2))
    p += 1

#file reading
searchfile = open("users.txt","r")
for line in searchfile:
    if username in line:
        print(line)
        passwordFile = next(searchfile)
        if hashValue == int(passwordFile):
            print("Succesfully logged in.")
        else:
            print("Denied.")
```

Comment: WORKS! Thank you very much!